# how to compare uploaded file in already exist in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting a file from the user and filter data from the model if the user uploaded file exists or not, but I am getting "None" while filtering.

```
from .models import SomeModel
uploaded_file = request.FILES.get('upload_file')

model_data = SomeModel.objects.filter(my_file=uploaded_file)
if model_data == None:
    someModel.objects.create(my_file=uploaded_file)
else:
    print('file already exist.')
print(model_data)  # prints None
```

I have uploaded the same file too many times but it always creates new data in the model.
I know every time when uploaded file Django creates a new file in the media folder.

how can I filter if uploaded_file already exists in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest both of these approaches. Why?

1. Because multiple users may upload files with same name. Even same user can upload it multiple times with same name (So many users simply upload `Untitles.xlsx`.
2. Every time a file is uploaded, it is stored in a temporary location for the GET dictionary (try /tmp on linux). So your temporary name/location may be different if the same named file exists.
3. The intention might be to reupload the same file. In that case you might want to update.

So a safer option would be to get the checksum of the file (md5/sha1/sha256) and even store that in the database. That will tell you if the file is indeed the same.
You can check the currently uploaded file for checksum.

Comment: thank you for suggesting file digestion. this can be implement